# Is it possible to do Subscripting in SVG?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I have drawn a bar chart using dimple.js. I have to show the yaxis labels and xaxis lables with subscript. Is it possible to show subscript in svg. If yes please let me know how to achieve subscripting in svg.

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/utfnLaz6/3/

```
var yMax = 1.2;
var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("body", 360, 360);
var dataChart = [{
    "Brand": "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO2": 10
}, {
    "Brand": "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO2": 20
},
                {
    "Brand": "Ccccccccccccccccc",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO2": 20
}];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, dataChart);
myChart.setBounds(120, 10, 200, 200)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SO2");
y.ticks = 5;
var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
s.barGap = 0.7;
myChart.draw();
console.log(y._tick_step)
```

In this i have to SO2 with 2 as subscript. Please let me know how to do that.

Comment: See http://www.svgbasics.com/font_effects_italic.html

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff  - ya i have seen that link but that are written with plain svg/html tags but in my case the data i have is in the form of json.. when i gave <tspan>2</tspan> it is displaying as it is not with the subscript..

Comment: it's not widely supported because the SVG CSS property conflicts with standard CSS. I expect SVG2 will offer a different solution.

Comment: @RobertLongson - why the unicode characters are also not working when i am giving in html areas it is working fine but in SVGs it is not working :(

Comment: @RobertLongson it is not a different question i just told that i tried that way too but it is not working. Overall the question is same how to do subscripting in SVG

Comment: via the dy attribute (and a different, smaller font-size if necessary)

Comment: @RobertLongson - even to set that dy attribute i need some tag right?? here the data is from json i donot have any tag for setting attributes. And even if i have a tag how to give dy attribute for a specific character in the text.

Comment: Looks like you can't do it then.

Comment: @RobertLongson :( :(

Comment: Well your question title is "Is it possible to do subscripting in SVG" The answer to that is yes. You need to figure out how to access the underlying SVG elements your charting library creates, or use a different library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack.  After your plot is drawn do:

```
var label = d3.select('.dimple-title.dimple-axis-y') //<-- find the axis label
d3.select(label.node().parentNode) //<-- add a new text with the subscript 2
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', label.attr('transform'))
    .attr('style', label.attr('style'))
    .attr('x', +label.attr('x') + 6)
    .attr('y', label.attr('y') - 5)
    .text('2');
```

Full Code:

```js
var yMax = 1.2;
var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("body", 360, 360);
var dataChart = [{
    "Brand": "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO": 10
}, {
    "Brand": "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO": 20
},
                {
    "Brand": "Ccccccccccccccccc",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SO": 20
}];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, dataChart);
myChart.setBounds(120, 10, 200, 200)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SO");
y.ticks = 5;
var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
s.barGap = 0.7;
myChart.draw();
console.log(y._tick_step)

var label = d3.select('.dimple-title.dimple-axis-y')
d3.select(label.node().parentNode)
    .append('text')
 .attr('transform', label.attr('transform'))
 .attr('style', label.attr('style'))
 .attr('x', +label.attr('x') + 6)
 .attr('y', label.attr('y') - 5)
 .text('2');
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dimple/2.1.6/dimple.latest.min.js"></script>
```